# Umbraco or MVC Razor Element with possible different CSS styles in beginning of tag

Tags: razor, umbraco

So I have seen this done before and I completely forgot where or what the syntax is.
Help is greatly appreciated.

So I have an element I want to add an CSS style to depending on what property is filled out or not in the Umbraco CMS.  I thought it involved colons (:) or something like that after the element's tag.  But not entirely sure.

I want to do something like this

```
 foreach(var item in @Model.myNodeList)
      if(@item.myProperty != String.Empty){
      <div class="myStyleOne">
      }
      else if(@item.myProperty == String.Empty){
      <div class="myStyleTwo">
      }
      else{
     <div class="myDefaultStyle">
      }
        <p>My content that will be inside of this div with different starting tags</p>
      </div>
 }
```

I know this code is not entirely correct and I am missing something. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just in case anyone else wanted to do this too.  I found out what it is.

This is the solution. It involves adding an @: sign in front of your elements' beginning and ending tags. 
Note: took out the last else. Thanks @Brandon for that.  That didn't make sense the first time.  Brandon's way or this way works too.

```
 foreach(var item in @Model.myNodeList)
    if(@item.myProperty != String.Empty){
    @:<div class="myStyleOne">
    }
    else if(@item.myProperty == String.Empty){
    @:<div class="myStyleTwo">
    }
    <p>My content that will be inside of this div with different starting tags</p>
    @:</div>
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)?

```
<div class="@(item.myProperty != String.Empty ? "myStyleOne" : "myStyleTwo")">
```

Seeing as the string is either empty or not, I'm not sure where your `myDefaultStyle` fits in.

This would work with inline styles as well. Using your example in the comment, it would look something like this

```
<div style="@(item.boxBackgroundColor != String.Empty ? "background-color:" + item.boxBackgroundColor + "; color:#fff !important" : "background-color:#fff;")">
```

Comment: Would this be the same case if I wanted to use a style tag instead of the class tag to insert inline styles (I know, bad practice, but in my case it is needed). And I had an property inside of the style tag that needed to be entered. Something like <div style="@(item.boxBackgroundColor != String.Empty ? "background-color:@(item.boxBackgroundColor); color:#fff !important" : "background-color:#fff;")">

Comment: @Carlos, yes. All that matters is that the condition will be evaluated and a value returned, in this case a string. You could change `class` to `style` and change `myStyleOne`/`myStyleTwo` to a CSS property if you wanted.

Comment: @Carlos, see edit. Because we've already opened an explicit code nugget (`@()`), you don't need to prefix `item` with `@` while inside. You will need to concatenate the string though.

Comment: That did the trick! Very insightful and educational.  Learn something new every day as they say.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`@:` and the `@Html.Raw()` method will do do same thing. However `@:` will let you keep typing html whereas `@Html.Raw()` expects a string.

You could clean up your code a bit by using a variable for the class:

```
foreach (var item in Model.myNodeList)
{
    string myClass = (item.myProperty != String.Empty) ? "myStyleOne" : "myStyleTwo";

    <div class="@myClass">
        <p>My content that will be inside of this div with the same starting tag</p>
    </div>
}
```